# Help "Non-finite value" Circuit Lab Error

Tags: led, circuitlab

After running DC Simulation in CircuitLab, I get this error message:

"Error building graph: non-finite value."

What is going on? I'm new at this, so anything could be wrong. First, to address and correct errors, I added SPICE values to all the LEDs, which cleared all errors but this one.

Here's the circuit:

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 3av343hdmban]

Edit updated 11:53EST 2/15/24:

Tried advice from "Andy aka" and removed the voltmeters and ampmeters from the circuit. Same error result:

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 4ddq42b2r54j]

Thanks for the suggestion, Andy! Any help appreciated!

Comment: this site has Circuit Lab built in ... edit your question ... click the circuit button ... build the circuit ... click "save and insert" ... done, no screenshots required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from putting voltmeters in series, your LED model has some crazy values in it, and that's the proximate cause of the issue:

[image]

Is should be many, many orders of magnitude less and R_S should be a positive value. These are SPICE diode model parameters- you can't just guess at them.

Here is one model I got from the manufacturer's [website](https://led.samsung.com/lighting/high-power-leds/3535-leds/lh351h-b/) (with a ridiculous number of (in)significant digits, but they do that sometimes), there are a number of models depending on the exact part and what you're trying to simulate, but this give a general idea of what kind of numbers to expect:

> .MODEL LH351B_AY_TYP D
>
> - IS=1.88444461164512E-25
> - N=1.79496204159106
> - RS=0.211993583775378
> - TRS1=0
> - TRS2=0
> - EG=2.5
> - XTI=30

As you can see the R_S (series resistive component of the forward drop) is a small positive value number of Ω, as you'd expect for a high-power LED, and the saturation current is around 24 orders of magnitude (\$10^{24}\$) smaller than the number you used. Diodes, like LEDs, with higher forward junction voltage have lower Is values than ordinary silicon diodes, and Schottky or germanium diodes have higher values, but still very small numbers.

Comment: OK, thank you Spehro Pefhany! I think this is a major part of my problem: the SPICE values which I inserted into the two LEDs are from an estimator program. I couldn't find any SPICE models with Samsung. Can you post a link and so I can search for LM301H-EVO and LH351H 660nm models?

Comment: Link attached, poke around the website to get the exact one and read the accompanying text files in the .zips.

Comment: Thanks again Spehro. I imported SPICE models and everything worked. Had to replace LM302H-EVO with LM301H_ONE model to approximate performance, but this seems acceptable. Here's a link to my new circuit v4, which replicates the Samsung Horticultural Gen2 module. [![CircuitLab Schematic 3c2g8eszq896](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/3c2g8eszq896/screenshot/540x405/)](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/3c2g8eszq896/gen2-repo-v4/)

Answer (score 3):

I think I see the problem (or a problem): -

[image]

You have a constant current generator (in the green box) but, it is feeding two voltmeters (red boxes) but, voltmeters have infinite terminal impedance hence, infinite voltage has to be generated by the current generator.

Try bypassing the voltmeters.

It seems you still have an error with the LEDs: -

[image]

Try selecting a standard model from the offered list.

Comment: Andy, thank you I'll try that right away.

Comment: @Effexxess let me know what happens please.

Comment: Hi! Just updated comment. And here's a new circuit [![CircuitLab Schematic 4ddq42b2r54j](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/4ddq42b2r54j/screenshot/540x405/)](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/4ddq42b2r54j/gen2-repro-v2/)

Comment: Try bypassing the LEDs with a resistor to ground from the CC source to see what happens. Make it 100 ohm @Effexxess

Comment: If that doesn't work try deleting the LEDs to see if they still have a model issue

Answer (score 0):

I imported SPICE models and everything worked!

Had to replace LM302H-EVO with LM301H_ONE model to approximate performance, but this seems acceptable.

Here's a link to my new circuit v4, which closely replicates the Samsung Horticultural Gen2 module.

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 3c2g8eszq896]

Comment: Effexxess It's good you posted the final solution so, If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification. You are quite at liberty to accept your own answer of course but, that might be seen as a little extreme given the help you have received.